# Can I be admitted to the US after a two-year overstay 21 years ago?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, overstaying

I overstayed my 90 day holiday waiver USA visa 21 years ago by about 2 years! I was young and foolish at the time. I so want to visit Graceland with my teenage daughter. Do I stand any chance at all? I've never tried to re-enter since I left. Should I apply for a Visa here and be honest I over stayed?

Answer (score 31):

Since you overstayed an entry on the Visa Waiver Program, you are forever ineligible to use the Visa Waiver Program again, according to [8 USC 1187(a)(7)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1187&num=0&edition=prelim#substructure-location_a_7), so (unless you have become a Canadian citizen) you would need to apply for a B2 visitor visa to visit the US. On the visa application form, it would ask whether you ever violated the terms of your status, and you would have to truthfully answer Yes and provide the details of that overstay.

When you stayed past the date you were admitted until on your I-94 (which was 90 days after your entry), assuming you were over 18, you started accruing "unlawful presence". By accruing more than 1 year of unlawful presence and then leaving the US, you triggered a 10-year ban under [8 USC 1182(a)(9)(B)(i)(II)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim#substructure-location_a_9_B_i_II). That ban is now long over, so you don't have to apply for a waiver. However, not having a ban doesn't mean you will get a visitor visa or be admitted as a visitor. Most types of nonimmigrant visas, including visitor visas, can be denied for "failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent", and any past negative history, especially a long overstay, can make it harder for you to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent in the determination of the officer.

Comment: After 21 years, if you life is really changed (married, good job, good reasons not to overstay again, etc.) you may have again chances (but no guarantee) But you need solid application (and correct: you need a Visa). Where you deported or did you left voluntarily? -- If you really need the visa: ask an immigration lawyer, else just try and be very honest (and careful not to make errors/assumptions) on your application. No guarantees.

Comment: No i was never deported... But id have a job.. Home.. Young kid at school here in Ireland... All can be shown as valid reasons to return home.... But can i Apply for the B1 or is it B2 visa before I book my flight? And will i have to go to American embassy for a interview?  I don't mind... My eldest was born in USA but I know that means no extra rights for me to return... I could kick myself for not having a proper visa years ago.. Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: @Rebecca Yes and yes. Basically you'll have to follow the process for countries not in the Visa Waiver Program. This includes applying for a B1/2 visa, and having an interview at the embassy.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info 

Comment: By the way when I apply for the B visa .. Do I have to have my flight already booked to do so … as I think it’s 185 USA dollars to apply and if they say no I’m then also down a flight fee too 

Comment: @Rebecca it's best to have a paid-for plane ticket. You can maybe try to get your ticket from an airline that allows cancellations without a fine?

Comment: @Rebecca you can always book a fully cancellable ticket, and if you're approved then you can cancel & rebook the same flight with a basic ticket for presumably much cheaper.

Comment: It's not just Canadians who can visit the US visa-free without using the VWP. Citizens of the freely associated states (the Marshall Islands, Palau, and the Federated States of Micronesia), British Overseas Territories citizens of Bermuda, the British Virgin Islands, the Cayman Islands, or the Turks and Caicos Islands, and nationals of the Bahamas also have visa-free access, as do Mexican government officials and airline crew members, and members of the Kickapoo tribes.

Comment: @Rebecca You typically [don't need to book any flights or hotels in advance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/104696) for US or UK visas (as opposed to e.g. Schengen visas in Europe), that's the official recommendation. The form will ask you about your travel _plans_, dates, and that better be specific. You likely can apply for a visa way in advance so tickets are still cheap when it's approved (or refused) during the interview.